# Base adapter - empty stack exception?

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I keep getting an `EmptyStackException` in `MyAdapter.java` (see below) even though the stack is not empty.

I checked and double checked everything, I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would me much appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package test.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayList<Stack<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Stack one = new Stack();
        one.push("a");
        one.push("b");
        list.add(one);

        Stack two = new Stack();
        two.push("c");
        two.push("d");
        list.add(two);

        lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,list));
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
package test.testapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Stack<String>> list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Stack<String>> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Stack<String> stack = (Stack) getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);

        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(stack.pop()); // <--- Empty stack exception here
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(stack.pop());

        return row;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="test.testapp.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingTop="20dp"
              android:paddingBottom="20dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's a strange design... Why would you want to put stacks there?

Comment: Please show the full logcat

Comment: Each item in the list has many sub items, so its a way of grouping the data per item. I'll probably change to a map later on though.

Comment: The `getView()` method is going to be called more often than you might think, and in no guaranteed order. You can't put any kind of logic like that there.

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think its necessary, key thing here is the `EmptyStackException`

Comment: @MikeM. Right, are there any alternatives for grouping data together per item?

Comment: ExpandableListView sounds like a better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not just popping the stack once.

Every single row item is popping the stack, and although you may have two items, I wouldn't be surprised if `getView` is being called more than twice

Try using a List of Lists, or a `Map<String, List<String>>` if you're looking for a ExpandableListView

Comment: "Every single row item is popping the stack" - True, but each row is only popping the stack that is for that row. Which is what we want.

Comment: No, it's not popping item for only that row. Lookup "listview recycling"

Comment: Adding `System.out.println` inside `getView` suggests otherwise?, it gets a specific position in the list, and that specific position in the list contains 1 stack which will be popped.

Comment: Okay, but again, views are in fact recycled if you had more of them. The `convertView` object determines that, and it's not one position  per View . That was my point. You're welcome to put a try catch around your stacks and continue to debug them.